# Cron executed successfully but product is not getting updated

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products, indexer

I setup the cronjob in Magento 2.1.7 but I got an unexpected result. All the indexer were updated except Product category an Category product when I add a new product.

Check in the cron_schedule table, but no exception found i.e, all the crons are updated succesfully.

Newly added product is not showing in category not in search. Cron has not throwing any error.

When I run the indexer manually then all product is shown.

Answer (score 1):

**My Suggestion to add the reindexing command as individual cron  like cron.php**

```
php5-cli  -d memory_limit=10G [MagentoDirectoryLocation]/bin/magento indexer:reindex >> [MagentoDirectoryLocation]//var/log/indexer.cron.log
```

*Add this comment to cron job list of server*

**Assume**: your `php client is  php5-cli`, this should same as  php client location of cron.php

Comment: I add an individual indexer command for the Product Categories, but this also raise an issue with the cache. But this is not the actual solution for the issue.